# NSLog Context Causing App Stuck

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a very weird error.

So I try to print my `NSManagedObjectContext` context. In the past my app worked perfectly. But just recently that my app got stuck on my below code:

```
NSLog("%@", context);
```

Anyone has same experience with me? I can remove that line for sure, but I am just curious why it happens.

Comment: "Got stucked"? Can you explain?

Comment: Yeah the app stucks, doesn't proceed to next code and without any error.

Comment: No SIG_ABORT or EXC_BAD_ACCESS or anything at all? No breakpoint?

Answer (score 1):

because the context isn't from your thread and printing it on another thread accesses it and causes a deadlock!

contextes arent really safe to use in multiple threads/queues

Comment: yeah actually I print it inside block `[operation setWillSendRequestForAuthenticationChallengeBlock:
  ^(NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *challenge)` which `operation` is `AFHTTPRequestOperation`. So it is not safe if I want to get some value from my Core Data entity inside that block?

Comment: check if the thread is the same thread as the one you created the context on (use 'dispatch_get_current_queue() for debugging!)